# Is it possible to get data from server when data been sent by Vue or React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, server

If not refresh browser, when data been set from server at intervals, does React or Vue has some features to get and show data immediately?

Generally, data is called by frontend, request to server, it seems it's difficult to call frontend to show data when it want.

Comment: If you want the server to initiate an update (i.e., without client polling), you'll probably need to use the [WebSocket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways you can do that.

1. Long polling: Client periodically ask server for the updated data. It was very popular before the arrival of SSE and WebSockets.
2. [SSE (Server-sent events)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events): Unidirectional way for server to send data to client.
3. [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API): Bidirectional way for both server and client to send data in real time. It is the most powerful of all the three options but equally challenging to setup since it involves completely new protocol `ws://` or `wss://` as opposed to traditional `https://`.

Considering your description in the question, I highly recommend Server-sent events.